# How to reserve jenkins agent for private use

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to find a way to get jenkins to allow a user to reserve an agent for private use. This is different to disabling an agent as the user reserving it may still want to run jenkins jobs on it. A simple use case is an agent is having problems running jobs, so it gets put into this reserved state while someone investigates what is going wrong.

I have tried a rather hacky solution using the ownership plugin, if the agent is owned by a dummy user called "free" or owned by the submitter of the job then the job will run, otherwise it will fail.

The problem with the solution I have is that:

- unless you go to a node you can't see who the owner is.
- it really needs a way to avoid trying to run the job on the agent instead of failing if it happens to choose one that has been reserved.

The other solution is to have a label "free" that someone would need to change when they want to reserve it to something like "reserved-bob", then have all the jobs take an extra label parameter which defaults to "free". The problem with this is:

- it's easy to make a mistake and not set the free label when unreserving the agent or leaving it on when adding the reserve label.
- not easy to find the set of nodes that aren't free

But it does have the advantage that anyone who knows the label could run jobs so it could be reserved by a team.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try this https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Ownership+Plugin

Comment: That's the plugin that I was using to implement the first solution

Answer (score 0):

So with a bit of playing I ended up creating 2 jobs, one which will reserve an agent and one which will free an agent. It works on the idea that an agent has a label user:everyone when it's available for everyone to use. When reserving it it changes the label to user: and also adds the e-mail address of the user (the next step is creating a job that reminds people if they have reserved something).

The code for reserving an agent is:

```
pipeline{
    agent {
        label "$SELECTION_CRITERIA && user:everyone"
    }
    stages {
        stage ( "Run"){
            steps {
                wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
                    script{
                        for (node in jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.nodes) {
                            if ( node.getNodeName() == "$NODE_NAME" ) {
                                oldLabelString = node.getLabelString()
                                if ( oldLabelString.contains("user:everyone") ) {
                                    oldLabelString = oldLabelString.replace("user:everyone","user:$NEWUSER")
                                    oldLabelString += " user-email:$BUILD_USER_EMAIL"
                                    node.setLabelString(oldLabelString)
                                    node.save()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

The code to then free it back is:

```
pipeline{
    agent {
        label "user:$OLDUSER"
    }
    stages {
        stage ( "Run"){
            steps {
                wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
                    script{
                        for (node in jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.nodes) {
                            if ( node.getNodeName() == "$NODE_NAME" ) {
                                oldLabelString = node.getLabelString()
                                if ( oldLabelString.contains("user:$OLDUSER") ) {
                                    oldLabelString = oldLabelString.replace("user:$OLDUSER","user:everyone")
                                    oldLabelString = oldLabelString.replaceAll(/ user-email:\S*/, "")
                                    node.setLabelString(oldLabelString)
                                    node.save()
                                }
                            }
                        }                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm fairly new to this so my guess is that you could do it in a nicer way (such as not loop through all nodes).

This removes the problem of users accidentally messing up the labels. Would still like it to be obvious if an agent has been reserved though.

Comment: That's a clever work-around. Still, I wish there was a plugin solution providing a better integration...